# How to access child component data in v-if outside of component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In short, I want to get a value from a child component and check what it is in the parent. I have a working implementation using computed properties and a reference via `v-ref` on the child component, but I was wondering if I am doing it the *right* way and if there's a better/proper way to do it.

To get to specifics, I have a component with checkboxes, the checked checkboxes' values within this component are kept in the components `data` in an array variable named `selected`. Outside of the component I want to conditionally show a `<div>` using `v-if` however I'm unsure how to correctly grab the child component's `selected` value.

Here's a brief overview of my code:

component mark up

```
<student-table
    v-ref:student-table
    :data="students"
    :course="course"
    :columns="columns"
>
</student-table>
```

component registration

```
Vue.component('student-table', {

    /* unrelated code */

    data: function () {
        return {
            selected: []
        }
    },

    /* unrelated code */
})
```

main vue instance

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
    /* unrelated code */

    computed: {
        selected: function () {
            return this.$refs.studentTable.selected.length
        }
    },

    /* unrelated code */
})
```

Then in my html I can reference `selected` and I'll get the length of `StudentTable.selected` and thus be able to use it in my `v-if`

Thanks for any guidance or help!

**Edit**

I'm getting this in my console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "function () {
    return this.$refs.studentTable.selected.length
}". Turn on debug mode to see stack trace.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to share data between parents / components such as 2-way binding between parent/child and also sending and listening for events.

Here is an events example with $broadcast and $dispatch:

parent vue:

```
var parentVue = new Vue({
     ...
     compiled: function(){
          this.$on('receiveDataFromChild', function(){
               //do something with the data from the child
          });
     },
     methods: {
          checkChildForData: function(){
               this.$broadcast('pleaseSendDataToYourMama');
          }
     }
});
```

child vue:

```
var childVue = new Vue({
     ...
     compiled: function(){
          this.$on('pleaseSendDataToYourMama', function(){
               this.$dispatch('receiveDataFromChild',this.someImportantData);
          });
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try to test this way out. Do you know if the current approach I'm taking is bad practice.

Comment: have you tried `return this.$refs.studentTable.$data.selected.length` ?

Comment: Still get the `console.warn` with `return this.$refs.studentTable.$data.selected.length`

Comment: I still believe you should just send the data via `$dispatch` when the child component is compiled;

Comment: The child `$on` doesn't appear to respond to the parent's `$broadcast`, do you think it's because it's in `compiled`? I added `events: { 'pleaseSendDataToYourMama': function () { ... }` to the child and it responds just fine.

Comment: not sure; I have not had issues setting it up in the `compiled` method before.  I'm glad you have it working

Answer (score 0):

This is how I now have it working, I'm not sure this is the best way but I'm not getting any `console.warn` alerts in my console. Would love any feedback. Many thanks to @Douglas.Sesar

```
// child
Vue.component('student-table', {

    parent: vueApp,

    data: function () {
        return {
            selected: []
        }
    },

    watch: {
        selected: function() {
            this.$dispatch('updateSelected', this.selected);
        }
    },

})

// parent
var vueApp = new Vue({

    components: {
        child: studentTable
    },

    data: {
        selected: []
    },

    events: {
        updateSelected: function(selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }
    },

})
```